# How to read the static file located in module A by calling module's A function from another module B?

Tags: go, module, io, static

I have the following directory structure:

```
module A
       |- static
       |    |- file.txt
       |- a.go
module B
       |- b.go
```

- in a.go I have a `func A()` that reads the content of the **static/file.txt** and returns it a result
- in b.go I have a `func main()` that calls `func A()` of the imported module A

When tested the main() func returns an error "can't find a file" as it tries to find the file in B/static/file.txt folder where the code is being executed.

What is the correct way to build the func A() to read attached to that module static file?

Comment: Files you open and read at runtime has no relationship to the packages. how you access a file depends on the current directory where your program is running, and where the file is relative to it.

Comment: Two things: 1. Those aren't modules, they're packages. 2. Neither packages, nor modules, contain files.

Answer (score 0):

Paths are relative to the directory in which the code is executed at run time. The fact that the file is contained in the same directory with a package does not mean it is associated with it. It would not be compiled with the package.

You'll have to pass the absolute path to the file `/path/to/static/file.txt` either through command-line arguments (using the `flags` module) or environment variable.

Using Flags

**In module A**

```golang
package A
import (
    "flag"
    "os"
)

func init() {
    var filePath = flag.String("filePath", "DEFAULT_PATH", "help message for flagname")
    file, err := os.Open(*filePath)
}
```

**Run in command line**

NB: main.go imports Package A

```
go run main.go -filePath=/path/to/file.txt
```

Using flags in the `init()` function can become tricky quickly so you can (and I strongly advise you to) use Envireonment variables instead.

For Linux based systems, add `export FILE_PATH=/path/to/file` in the `.profile` or `.bashrc` file contained in your `$HOME` path.
Also run `source .profile` or `source .basrc` depending on which file was edited to make the changes immediate.

Then you can update **package A** to look like this:

```golang
package A
import (
    "os"
)

func init() {
    file, err := os.Open(os.Getenv("FILE_PATH"))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you gonna ignore the path of runtime you can try runtime.Caller(0) (not recommended, full file path may better than this solution)

inside a.go

```
_, f, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
dirPath := filepath.Dir(file)

file, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(dirPath, "static", "file.txt"))
```